# Outlook calendar events sync like Google Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, google-calendar-api, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I have a web application in which users can sign up for "Events". I can sync those events directly to the user's google calendar if they have a gmail email ID registered. I am trying to check if the same is possible for Outlook users.

On checking the Microsoft Graph, they do have the API to create, modify and delete calendar events on Outlook calendar but I am having trouble setting up the authentication and authorization part of it. From what I understood they have two ways in which I can use the API - Delegate and Application. For delegate API, a UI will pop where it will ask the user to sign in and then all the API will assume that user identity for the operations.
For Application API, there is no sign in page but no user is associated with the call either, so only generic type of APIs work where no user is involved.
Since I want to integrate this in the web app, is it possible to have a setup where server is able to send event requests on behalf from my account?

Comment: If you're looking to use the MS Graph API, you will need delegated access to read/write events in the user's outlook calendar (specifically: `Calendars.ReadWrite`). This is granted via the standard OAuth flow. Note that this is quite similar to how it works for Google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

1. Send the user an invite from your account, you will need the webserver to use your account. Either by login in yourself and caching & refreshing the token. Or by using your own tenant and doing it with admin consent and application credentials.
2. Have the user login and directly add the item to their calendar. If the user has a business account, you will probably never be authorized to access calendars. Since this is considered as a pretty serious consent.

Alternative way is the offer the event as an ics file. That way the user can download it, and if they have Outlook installed the item will be added to their calendar automatically.

Comment: Thanks for replying, does the user has to download the ics file for it to be added to the calendar?

Comment: Yes the user has to download the ics file, but I think Outlook registers a file handler for ICS files. So download and open should work.